# Python multiprocessing poor performance

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, pool, ray

I have to run a prediction using prophet on a certain number of series (several thousands).
prophet works fine but does not make use of multiple CPU. Each prediction takes around 36 seconds (actually the whole functions that makes also some data preprocessing and post-elaborations). If I run sequentially (for just 15 series to make a test) it takes 540 seconds to complete. Here is the code:

```
for  i in G:
    predictions = list(make_prediction(i, c, p))
```

where G is an iterator that returns a series at a time (capped for the test at 15 series), c and p are two dataframes (the functions uses them only to read).

I then tried with **joblib**:

```
predictions = Parallel(n_jobs=5)( delayed(make_prediction)(i, c, p) for i in G)
```

Time taken 420 seconds.

Then I tried **Pool**:

```
p = Pool(5)
predictions = list(p.imap(make_prediction2, G))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Since with map I can pass just one parameter, I call a function that calls make_prediction(G, c,p). Time taken 327 seconds.

Eventually I tried **ray**:
I decorated make_prediction with #@ray.remote and called:

```
predictions = ray.get([make_prediction.remote(i, c, p) for i in G])
```

time taken: 340 seconds! I also tried to make c and p ray objects with c_ray = ray.put(c) and the same for p and passing c_ray and p_ray to the functions but I could not see any improvement in performance.

I understand the overhead required by forking and actually the time taken from the function is not huge, but I'd expect better performance (less than 40% gain, at best, using 5 time as much CPUs does not seem amazing) especially from ray. Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Any idea to get better performances?

Let me point out that RAM usage is under control. Each process, in the worst scenario, uses less than 2GB of memory so less than 10 in total with 26 GB available.

Python 3.7.7 Ray 0.8.5 joblib 0.14.1 on Mac os X 10.14.6 i7 with 4 physical cores and 8 threads (cpu_count() = 8; with 5 cpu working no throttle reported by pmset -g thermlog)

PS Increasing the test size to 50 series the performance improves, especially with ray, meaning that the overhead of forking is relevant in such a small test. I will make a longer test to have a more accurate performance metric but I guess I won't go far from 50% a value that seems consistent with other posts I have seen where to have a 90% reduction they used 50CPUs.

**************************** UPDATE ***********************************

Increasing the number of series to work to 100, **ray** hasn't showed good performances (maybe I miss something in its implementation). **Pool**, instead, using *initializer* function and *imap_unordered* went better. There is a tangible overhead caused by forking and preparing each process environment, but I got really weird results:

- a single CPU took 2685 seconds to complete the job (100 series);
- using pool as described above with 2 CPUs took 1808 seconds (**-33%** and it seems fine);
- using the same configuration with 4 CPUs took 1582 seconds (-41% compared to single CPU but just -12,5% compared to the 2 CPUs job).

**Doubling the number of CPU for just 12% of time decrease?** Even worse using 5 CPUs takes nearly the same time (please note than 100 can be evenly divided by 1, 2, 4 and 5 so the queues are always filled)! No throttle, no swap, the machine has 8 cores and plenty of unused CPU power even when running the test, so no bottlenecks. What's wrong?

Comment: how many cores does your computer have?  how do know prophet doesn't make use of multiple CPUs?  maybe run `top` or similar to see what your machine is actually doing.  I'd suggest putting your comments into the actual question, they are relevant details (as are the versions / OS)

Comment: What does your worker return?  A very common multiprocessing issue with Python is data transfer. Data in and out of workers is handled using queues, which work but are not stellar performers.   If your return structures are large, you can see if it this is the issue by returning something very small instead of a massive list or dictionary. If performance improves, you need to consider other means to improve efficiency.

Comment: Well if I run prophet it will create a single process that won't use more than 100% of CPU. If I use multiprocess I can have "n" processes in parallel all near 100%. No the return set is just one month predictions data so really tiny.  Question updated, thanks